# return date is wrong in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I am new to hibernate. I used MYSQL database. there is date field in my table. its type is DATE. There is a value 1989-08-13. When I get value using hibernate it gives that date as 6189498000000. I want to get value as real date (1989-08-13). Please help me

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Aug 27, 2013 1:03:09 AM by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="core.classes.Staff" table="staff" catalog="surgercare">
        <id name="staffId" type="int">
            <column name="staff_ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="staffName" type="string">
            <column name="staff_Name" length="150" />
        </property>
        <property name="staffDesignation" type="string">
            <column name="staff_designation" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="createDate" type="timestamp">
            <column name="CreateDate" length="19" />
        </property>
        <property name="createUser" type="string">
            <column name="CreateUser" length="200" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastUpDate" type="timestamp">
            <column name="LastUpDate" length="19" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastUpDateUser" type="string">
            <column name="LastUpDateUser" length="200" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My class file

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Staff implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int staffId;
    private String staffName;
    private String staffDesignation;
    private Date createDate;
    private String createUser;
    private Date lastUpDate;
    private String lastUpDateUser;

    public Staff() {
    }

    public Staff(int staffId) {
        this.staffId = staffId;
    }

    public Staff(int staffId, String staffName, String staffDesignation,
            Date createDate, String createUser, Date lastUpDate,
            String lastUpDateUser) {
        this.staffId = staffId;
        this.staffName = staffName;
        this.staffDesignation = staffDesignation;
        this.createDate = createDate;
        this.createUser = createUser;
        this.lastUpDate = lastUpDate;
        this.lastUpDateUser = lastUpDateUser;
    }

    public int getStaffId() {
        return this.staffId;
    }

    public void setStaffId(int staffId) {
        this.staffId = staffId;
    }

    public String getStaffName() {
        return this.staffName;
    }

    public void setStaffName(String staffName) {
        this.staffName = staffName;
    }

    public String getStaffDesignation() {
        return this.staffDesignation;
    }

    public void setStaffDesignation(String staffDesignation) {
        this.staffDesignation = staffDesignation;
    }

    public Date getCreateDate() {
        return this.createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

    public String getCreateUser() {
        return this.createUser;
    }

    public void setCreateUser(String createUser) {
        this.createUser = createUser;
    }

    public Date getLastUpDate() {
        return this.lastUpDate;
    }

    public void setLastUpDate(Date lastUpDate) {
        this.lastUpDate = lastUpDate;
    }

    public String getLastUpDateUser() {
        return this.lastUpDateUser;
    }

    public void setLastUpDateUser(String lastUpDateUser) {
        this.lastUpDateUser = lastUpDateUser;
    }

}
```

this is my controller

```
tx = ses.beginTransaction();
Query query = ses.createQuery("select s from Staff as s where  s.staffId = :ID");
query.setString("ID", docID);
List<Staff> DocDetailsList = castlist(Staff.class,query.list());
tx.commit();
return DocDetailsList;
```

Comment: You haven't told us which field is giving you problems, which doesn't help...

Comment: There are 2 Dates in java: java.util.Date and java.sql.Date... make sure you wont mix up the two.

Comment: 618984000 is 1989-08-13 12:00am in UNIX time notation. What you have there is the milliseconds representation of same.

Comment: the lastUpDate column is the one giving you problems? i noticed property type is timestamp and in file is date. Hope this helps.

Comment: I cannot see any field in type of Integer, except `staffId`. So could you post the code that gives date as 6189498000000?

Comment: every date field give same kind of value
@tadman how can i get normal date from millisecond representation

Answer (score 1):

In your hbm file, there are "timestamp" column type. Let hibernate guess the column type:

```
<property name="createDate" column="CreateDate" />
```

In other words, if you have the following property:

```
java.util.Date createDate;
```

hibernate3-maven-plugin hibernate3:hbm2ddl goal will create the following column in MySql:

```
`CreateDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL
```

**Note**: datetime and timestamp have different ranges. Same for Java Long (timestamp) and java.util.Date.